# error at create .net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to create new .net core web application project and see this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.MicrosoftAzure.AzureFunctions,Version=15.0.0.0'

what can I do?

Comment: How are you creating it? What version of .NET Core are you using?

Comment: File>New Project>.Net Core>Asp.NET Core Web Application
.net core ver=2.1.2

Comment: That's weird, that package has nothing to do with a blank Razor Pages app. How about if you create one from command line: `dotnet new razor -o testapp`, then `cd testapp`, then `dotnet run` ?

Comment: that's ok
I don't know what happened